# How to split a dynamic array into subarrays

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose you are given an array

```
    $input = array(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5);
```

Where you want to split the array so that you have all the 1's in one array, all the 2's in one array, etc.

However, you don't know if the $input array will only contain only 1's, or only 1's and 2's, or how many ever numbers there are.

The numbers are numerically ordered.

Comment: The famous question. what have you tried?

Comment: Is this some kind of homework question?

Comment: Loop through the array. If the value is the same as the previous value, add the element to that array. If not, start a new array with the new value.

Comment: Ok, I'm supposing...

Answer (score 2):

array_count_values() may help you, see link below for example.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: That's only going to give an array of each value with a corresponding count, not an array with each of the values in an array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple one, just set the key and the value and build nested arrays like so.

```
    $input = array(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5);
    $output = array();
    foreach ( $input as $i ){
        if(!isset( $output[$i] ) ){
            $output[$i] = array();
        }
        $output[$i][] = $i;

    }
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export( $output );
```

Outputs

```
    array (
            1 =>
            array (
                    0 => 1,
                    1 => 1,
                    2 => 1,
            ),
            2 =>
            array (
                    0 => 2,
                    1 => 2,
            ),
            3 =>
            array (
                    0 => 3,
                    1 => 3,
            ),
            4 =>
            array (
                    0 => 4,
            ),
            5 =>
            array (
                    0 => 5,
                    1 => 5,
            ),
    )
```

inputs

```
    $input = array(1,2,3,3,4,2,3,1,8,7);
```

Outputs

```
    array (
            1 =>
            array (
                    0 => 1,
                    1 => 1,
            ),
            2 =>
            array (
                    0 => 2,
                    1 => 2,
            ),
            3 =>
            array (
                    0 => 3,
                    1 => 3,
                    2 => 3,
            ),
            4 =>
            array (
                    0 => 4,
            ),
            8 =>
            array (
                    0 => 8,
            ),
            7 =>
            array (
                    0 => 7,
            ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned with performance, a simple loop and `array_slice()` can be used. Keep track of where you are in the `$input` array, and slice the array when the value changes.

```
$input = array(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5);
$curr = $input[0];
$count = 0;
$offset = 0;
$length = 0;
$result_array = array();
foreach($input as $i)
{
  if($i != $curr)
  {
    $result_array[] = array_slice($input, $offset, $length);
    $curr = $i;
    $offset = $count;
    $length = 0;
  }
  $count++;
  $length++;
}
$result_array[] = array_slice($input, $offset);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not real sure what you're seeking specifically, but if you want them separated into an array of like values grouped into arrays:

```
$input = array(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5);
$parts = array_count_values($input);

foreach ($parts as $key => $val) {
    $parts[$key] = array_fill(0, $val, $key);
}
```

http://codepad.org/cxAL71r8

And if the keys need to be sequential and not related to your values:

```
$parts = array_values($parts);
```

http://codepad.org/zHFpHBTY

If this *is homework*, you should really try to do it first. If you did, it's always best to provide what you tried in the question.